# Join fetch property of embeddable in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

These are my mapped classes:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
...
     @ElementCollection
     @CollectionTable(name = "BID")
     private Set<Bid> bids = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
@Immutable
public class Bid implements Serializable {
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User bidder;
...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class User {
...
}
```

**Is there a way to query all bids and join fetch all bidders to avoid n+1 problem?**

It will be smth like this

```
session.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Item i " +
                "JOIN i.bids b " +
                "JOIN FETCH b.bidder", Bid.class)
```

but this fails with:
`org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list[FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null.bidder...]`

I know that making Bid class entity instead of embeddable will solve the problem, but i am interested is there any way how to do this with this mapping

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in older Hibernate versions. Try updating to the latest 5.4 version.

Comment: I'm using hibernate 5.4.25.Final

Comment: I guess Hibernate considers `Item` as being the owner of `bids` and also `bids.bidder` because `bids` is an element collection. You could use DTOs instead where you don't need fetch joins at all and can control exactly the data that you want to fetch. Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views might come in handy here: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage